Flutter app last release not updated in firbease console
We recently updated our app to version 2.5.4 and successfully released it on both the Play Store and the Apple Store. In Firebase, the iOS version correctly shows as 2.5.4, but the Android version still shows as an old version, 2.2.0, we just pay attention to this!
We are confused why Firebase is not displaying the latest version for our Android app. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on how to resolve this?
any help will be appreciated.

Which section in Firebase console you mention? Release Monitoring, Analytics Dashboard, Audiences.....? btw I think just wait some hours for data metrics up to date

in Latest Release section.
it is not a question of waiting for data to update, this 2.2.0 is around for a long time.

To everyone facing the issue, we figured out a fix by using Firebase CLI to configure Firebase in the Flutter app instead of doing it manually — the old approach.
It seems that we missed something using the old approach.
